# com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0 not working

Tags: android, firebase

I did everything by following the [instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/android#create_a_product_name_project_for_the_quickstart_sample). But `mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(cacheExpiration)` haven't been working.

But when I changed a version to the earlier in my app build gradle file from

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.4'
```

it's become working..

Do you have any idea, what can be the reason of it?

Also I checked in my previous projects. I changed the version from 11.0.4 to 16.0.0 and fetching stoped working...

**my app build gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bestworldgames.bestwordgame"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.inkapplications.viewpageindicator:library:2.4.3'
    implementation 'com.startapp:inapp-sdk:3.8.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation('cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager:android-auto-scroll-view-pager:1.1.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**my project gradle file**:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> Added:

`mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(cacheExpiration)` not working is mean that `public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)` haven't been called.

```
mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(cacheExpiration)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fetch Succeeded",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // After config data is successfully fetched, it must be activated before newly fetched
                    // values are returned.
                    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fetch Failed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                displayWelcomeMessage();
            }
        });
```

logcat:

```
06-04 17:39:55.966 10786-10826/com.bestwordgame W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date. Requires 12451000 but found 11509470 
06-04 17:39:55.966 10786-10786/com.bestwordgame W/FA: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
```

The promlem is in emulator, I guess.. But now I can't find Google Play settings in the emulator's extanded window.. If I'm right, Is there another way to  update Google Play Services on emulator?

This is my SDK Settings
[image]

with 'Show package details':

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "haven't been working."?

Comment: What does logcat say?

Comment: [Levi Albuquerque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7765139/levi-albuquerque), it'is mean that `public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)`  haven't been called. I've added it in the question.

Comment: [Doug Stevenson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126/doug-stevenson): 
 `06-04 17:39:55.966 10786-10826/com.bestworldgames.bestwordgame W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11509470
06-04 17:39:55.966 10786-10786/com.bestworldgames.bestwordgame W/FA: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}`

Comment: [Doug Stevenson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126/doug-stevenson), the promlem is in emulator, I guess.. But now I can't find Google Play settings in the emulator's extanded window..))

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem is in emulator. But also I've found out that it's better to check the device for a compatible Google Play services by `GoogleApiAvailability.makeGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` method.
See [the link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-play).

It's my verification method, wich I call at onCreate():

```
 private void checkGooglePlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int status = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        Log.i("TAG", "AppController checkGooglePlayServices status " + status);
        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            api.makeGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
```

> Your app gradle file now has to explicitly list com.google.firebase:firebase-core as a dependency for Firebase services to work as expected.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: [Peter Haddad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7015400/peter-haddad), Sorry, I've just added a code of gradle files. I already have this one..

Comment: [Peter Haddad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7015400/peter-haddad): `06-04 17:39:55.966 10786-10826/com.bestworldgames.bestwordgame W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date. Requires 12451000 but found 11509470 06-04 17:39:55.966 10786-10786/com.bestworldgames.bestwordgame W/FA: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}`

Comment: are u using genymotion?

Comment: [Peter Haddad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7015400/peter-haddad), no, I use AVD provided in Android Studio

Comment: try and test on a physical device, to check if the problem also occurs

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem. I just replaced the `google()` by maven `{ url 'https://maven.google.com'  }`, then it started working.

Refer the quickstart app [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/config/build.gradle).